# Switched outlet on when lights are off

Tags: multiway-switch

I have a 3 way switch working the lights in my son’s room. The box has a single 14/3 cable running to the switch. Id like to put an outlet directly below it the would ideally be always on. I can't figure out how I'd accomplish this without the switch also working the outlet. If it does have to be a switched outlet can I wire it so the outlet is on when the lights are off? I'd like to put a night light in the outlet.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Answer (score 4):

A 14/3 with a 3-way switch is going to be:

- Traveler 1
- Traveler 2
- Either hot (in) or switched hot (out)

That means you don't have a **neutral**, which is a must for a receptacle (switched or not).

However, there **might** be a solution if you can use **smart switches**. Many 3-way smart switches only need **one traveler**. You could, potentially, install smart switches and then rewire things so that you have:

- Traveler
- Hot
- Neutral

and pass the hot & neutral on to a receptacle. Doing this could get a bit confusing, so if you want to look into this, **before you disconnect anything**, upload pictures of the wires going into each of the 3-way switches.

Comment: Good answer, with the new code having the neutral on the box will keep us from having this problem.